# HTTP post doesn't send special characters correctly

Tags: php, mysql, html, post, encoding

I have two .php files, a form with a text field where you put the names you want to search in the database, and a results file that processes the post...

The names in the database will be searched using this query:

```
SELECT * FROM acw_papers_web web 
INNER JOIN acw_papers_web_autores aut 
ON web.id_paper_web = aut.id_paper_web 
WHERE aut.nombre_autor_pw LIKE '%autorname%' 
ORDER BY web.probabilidad DESC
```

The problem is that when I send the post, insted of sending lópez, it sends lÃ³pez...

How can I fix it... both .php files are utf-8 encoded...

Comment: There's no such thing as an "HTML post" ... `HTTP POST` on the other hand ...

Comment: Please provide the PHP code and HTML that handles this.

Comment: Sounds like a charset mismatch. You need to maintain the same character set throughout the entire pipeline: webpage, http connection, database connection, database table, etc... if there's a diferent charset in play at even just ONE of those stages, you'll get that mangled text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you did not provide much information, I cannot exactly pinpoint the problem. But here are two possible solutions:

1. Set the correct charset in the `<head>` of both files:

   `<meta charset="UTF-8" />` for HTML5 or `<meta http-eqiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />` for everything else
2. Set the character set of the database tables to UTF-8. In MySQL:

   `ALTER TABLE acw_papers_web CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;` 
   `ALTER TABLE acw_papers_web_autores CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;`

That's all I could think of, for now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use
urlencode() - URL-encodes string
urldecode() - URL-decode
Functions to send special characters in the Post Request.